# Why aren't NoSQL Databases ACID compliant?

Tags: database, nosql, acid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any NoSQL that is ACID compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608103/is-there-any-nosql-that-is-acid-compliant)

So, I heard NoSQL Databases are not ACID compliant, why is this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608103/is-there-any-nosql-that-is-acid-compliant

Comment: Yo, dawg! So, I heard you like NoSQL Databases....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781542/what-applications-dont-need-acid/7708573#7708573

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754219/what-are-some-real-world-implications-of-non-acid-database-compliance/7897462#7897462

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't necessarily true - it depends on which particular database you're referring to. Some of them (for example Neo4j) are fully ACID compliant. Check out this link for a comparison of some NoSQL databases: http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, ACID compliance imposes performance overhead.  NoSql performance is enhanced by this lack of performance overhead.