# Nosql does not support to ACID property then why some companies using NoSql databases

Tags: cassandra

Nosql does not support to ACID property then why some companies using NoSql databases  Like Facebook uses Cassandra and Amazon uses dynamodb

Comment: I happen to like this article by Jon Haddad discussing how "safe" you really are with ACID: http://rustyrazorblade.com/2015/06/youre-already-eventually-consistent/

Comment: Why do you think ACID operations are mandatory?

Comment: refer to my response in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160732/nosql-vs-relational-database/31968494?s=28|0.0000#31968494

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754219/what-are-some-real-world-implications-of-non-acid-database-compliance/7897462#7897462 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781542/what-applications-dont-need-acid

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781542/what-applications-dont-need-acid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754219/what-are-some-real-world-implications-of-non-acid-database-compliance/+

Answer (score 1):

Companies use Cassandra when they need their application to scale to use many servers for higher capacity and higher reliability by keeping redundant copies of data on multiple servers.

In many cases ACID transactions are not needed for building a correctly functioning system.

Databases which have good support for ACID transactions are often limited to a single server, so they do not scale.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cosmos DB and be happy as it supports all most everything you need for data :

Here is the FAQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/faq